# Nested blocks on sonata show action

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to build a show view like this, with sonata :

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|   PAGE                                            |
|                                                   |
|   +---------------------------+   +-----------+   |
|   |   BLOCK 1                 |   |   BLOCK 2 |   |
|   |  +--------+   +-------+   |   |           |   |
|   |  | 1.1    |   | 1.2   |   |   |           |   |
|   |  |        |   |       |   |   |           |   |
|   |  |        |   |       |   |   |           |   |
|   |  |        |   |       |   |   |           |   |
|   |  +--------+   +-------+   |   |           |   |
|   +---------------------------+   +-----------+   |
|                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I know you can build BLOCK 1 and BLOCK 2 with the "with()" method, but I don't see any way to nest BLOCK 1.1 and 1.2 inside BLOCK 1. I don't want to use tabs, I want everything on the same page.

Any way to nest more than 1 level of blocks ?

Comment: I never tried this. You could try override CoreController of sonata admin bundle and the template (if we are talking about dashboard, if not than create the logic of rendering in your own controller) and create some own logic of rendering blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You have show action. And you you use, let's say two blocks (`I mean ->with()` ). 
Also you have in both of blocks different fields. You can overwrite the template of one of the fields and whatever you want inside that template. You can event create blocks (with sonata styles), which will look like thous, which are made by sonata `->with()`.

In sonata admin:

```
->with('Block1')
    ->add('your_field', null, [
          'required' => false,
          'template'  => 'AppBundle::Admin\path_to_your_template\show_some_field.html.twig',
    ])
->end()
```

And your template:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {#  Make here whatever you want #}
    {{ object.your_field }}
{% endblock field%}
```

I can propose a sample if you will need it.